# Wiremock, get request mappings with absoluteUrl that shows host

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am checking all the stubs using http://localhost:9001/__admin/mappings.
Pls can you tell if there is a flag we can add in this path http://localhost:9001/__admin/mappings, which can list all mappings with absoluteUrl, just not urlPathPattern.

I see a request mismatch. All the request is matching , but have to figure out if host is also matching.

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you add more information about the mismatch? I wouldn't guess that the host would cause the issue, as the host is the same for all requests that reach your WireMock instance.
FWIW I'm not aware of any flag that will add the absolute URL instead of relative URL, mostly for the reason listed above.